# Split vendor bundle

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, webpack-3, commonschunkplugin

My vendor bundle is getting really big and I want to split into 2 parts. (One part with all the react related packages, and the other with the rest of the packages).

What I currently have to create the vendor bundle is:

```
new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
  name: ['vendor'],
  filename: '[name].bundle.js',
  minChunks: module => module.context.includes('node_modules')
})
```

I tried adding these different approaches below, but no success so far:

```
// approach 1
new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
  name: 'react',
  chunks: ['vendor'],
  minChunks: ({resource}) => (/node_modules\/react/).test(resource)
})

// approach 2
new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
  name: ['react'],
  filename: '[name].bundle.js',
  minChunks: ({resource}) => (/node_modules\/react/).test(resource)
})
```

The split happens, but I cannot run in the browser. In my console I get:

```
vendor.bundle.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: webpackJsonp is not defined
at vendor.bundle.js:1

(anonymous) @ vendor.bundle.js:1 
12:52:57.478 react.bundle.js:55 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined
at __webpack_require__ (react.bundle.js:55)
at eval (react.development.js:18)
at eval (react.development.js:1356)
at Object.603 (react.bundle.js:747)
at __webpack_require__ (react.bundle.js:55)
at eval (index.js:6)
at Object.0 (react.bundle.js:156)
at __webpack_require__ (react.bundle.js:55)
at eval (index.jsx:8)
at Object.<anonymous> (client.bundle.js:1375)
```

I've already loaded the new file with the  tag in my html.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just solved the issue using the following solution:

```
new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
  name: ['vendor'],
  filename: '[name].bundle.js',
  minChunks: module => module.context.includes('node_modules') && !module.request.includes('scss')
}),

new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
  name: 'react',
  chunks: ['vendor'],
  minChunks: ({resource}) => (/node_modules\/react/).test(resource)
}),
```

Answer (score 0):

One easy way to deal with it is to specify the content of your vendor and react in entry property like this :

```
entry: {
    app: ['./src/index.js'],
    react: [
      'react',
      'react-dom'],
    vendor: [
      'other-libraries',
    ]
  }
```

Then you can specify these entries in CommonsChunkPlugin like this:

```
new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
      name: ['react', 'vendor']
    })
```

Comment: By running this approach I end up getting this error on my log: `ERROR in CommonsChunkPlugin: While running in normal mode it's not allowed to use a non-entry chunk (react)`

Comment: Which version of webpack are you using?

Comment: I am using webpack@3.5.3

Comment: It should work. I using this approach with webpack@3.8.1